# Podemos usar todas as versões do css no nosso site?

Tags: css

Atualmente existe a versão css3 no entanto existem as anteriores. É correto misturar código de todas elas na mesma folha de estilo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As versões de CSS diferentes são retro compatíveis entre sí. Isso quer dizer que código em CSS2 e CSS3 podem estar presentes na mesma página, ou folha de estilo.

O que não é compativel, ou seja a diferença é qual versão de CSS que os browsers suportam. Uma versão antiga do Internet Explorer pode não suportar CSS3 (ou algumas das suas regras). Assim nesse caso o CSS2 pode correr bem, mas o CSS3 não.

Portanto a mistura não tem problema. O problema que pode ter é alguns browsers não suportarem regras de CSS mais modernas.